# Parse error PHP short tag

Tags: php, parsing

I have the following error and cant determine how to fix it,

This is My code:

```
<h2><?=$facility['name']?></h2>
<=$facility['street'].''.$facility['city'].''.$facility['state'].''.=$facility['postal_code'].''.$facility['phone']?>
```

and i get the following error:

> Parse error"';' expected after PHP short tag '

I appreciate any help.

Comment: `<=` on line two should be `<?=`

Comment: You're not terminating your lines with semicolons. Also, the second tag is wrong - you've missed the `?`.

Comment: @andrewsi You don't need a semi-colon with short tags (or ever on the last line before a `?>`) in PHP.

Comment: Beware the portability of short_tags. While they might save you a few characters now, it's quite common for them to be disabled, so most would recommend avoiding them

Comment: and please avoid using short tags http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse It's becoming quite uncommon for them to be disabled as they are now built-in to PHP (the `<?=` version, `<?` is still not recommended).

Comment: @Paulpro - huh, I didn't know that. Clearly I don't use short tags enough :)

Comment: @Paulpro Aparently impossible to disable `<?=` after 5.4.0... Thanks for letting me know :) (`<?=''.''.''?>` is just ugly imo).

Comment: @andrewsi It's not just short tags. The last line before `?>` no matter how long the section of PHP is doesn't need it. `PHP` treats semi-colons as an "instruction separator" rather than an "end of statement delimiter": http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php

Comment: @Paulpro - oh, yes; I knew PHP uses semi-colons as a line separator rather than a line terminator, but I didn't know short tags didn't need one at all. I've always used them no matter what, on the grounds of 'it can't hurt'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With everyones help, your code should look like this:

```
<h2><?=$facility['name']?></h2>
<?=$facility['street'].''.$facility['city'].''.$facility['state'].''.$facility['postal_code'].''.$facility['phone']?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?=$facility['street'].''.$facility['city'].''.$facility['state'].''.=$facility['postal_code'].''.$facility['phone']?>
```

Comment: you guys are both not seeing the second `=` next to `$facility['postal_code']`